# Mapped Array with component not rendering on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm Building a quiz app which gets the questions and answers from an API, it comprises of the start page and another page to display the questions and answers, I previously set a state `start`  to switch between the Boolean values to know when to render the questions , but my mapped array of `request` isn't rendering on the page with the `Question` component.
The App code as well as the Question is below,
I want to make it that on clicking the button, the mapped question is rendered

```js
const [start, setStart] = React.useState(true)
console.log(start)

function renderNextPage() {
  setStart(false)
}


const [request, setRequest] = React.useState([])


React.useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setRequest(data.results.map(({
      question,
      correct_answer,
      incorrect_answers
    }) => ({
      question,
      correct_answer,
      incorrect_answers
    }))))
}, [])



const questionElements = request.map(req => {
  return ( <
    Question question = {
      req.question
    }
    />
  )
})

return (
  start ? < Start handleClick = {
    renderNextPage
  }
  />  : {questionElements}

)
}



// QUestion Component

export default function Question(props) {

  return ( <div >
    <h1 > {
      props.question
    }
    working </h1>

    <
    /div>

  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen, because your question elements are not wrapped into a parent component. Hence, you might want to use your question elements like this:

`<div>{questionElements}</div?`

However, I would recommend using [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/navigate) library, when you need multiple pages.